Customize title in Amplify Authenticator in flutter
I am trying to update the text "Log in using", and preferably remove it. I did not find anything to do that. I am using a mix of prebuilt ui with customization in flutter amplify_authenticator package.

I have tried all AuthStringResolver as follows.
AuthStringResolver AuthStringResolver({
  ButtonResolver? buttons,
  DialCodeResolver? dialCodes,
  InputResolver? inputs,
  MessageResolver? messages,
  TitleResolver? titles,
  InstructionsResolver? instructions,
})

They work for pretty much all the text in different components. However, I could not change the title of tab. Any help regarding this would much appreciated.
